# How to mock a exception during df.write in pyspark unit tests?

Tags: python, unit-testing, apache-spark, pyspark, opensearch

I'm writing a Pyspark dataframe to OpenSearch, and I need to ensure retries and exponential backoff in case OpenSearch starts throttling the incoming requests. Retries are built in, but I'm seeing mixed answers online about whether or not it'll do exponential backoff by default... so I want to test it out myself.

Here's my (unpolished) code to write to OpenSearch. (If it matters, I'm running this on Databricks using the [Opensearch-hadoop 1.0.1 library](https://github.com/opensearch-project/opensearch-hadoop/releases/tag/v1.0.1) attached to my cluster. Cluster is Spark 3.5 with Scala 2.12 and Python 3.10).

```
    def write_df_to_opensearch(self, df, index_nm):
        # retry.policy simple will retry for 429 (Too Many Requests) and 503 (Unavailable) exceptions from Opensearch
        df.write\
            .format("org.opensearch.spark.sql")\
            .option("inferSchema", "true")\
            .option("opensearch.nodes", self.hostname)\
            .option("opensearch.port", self.port)\
            .option("opensearch.net.http.auth.user", self.username)\
            .option("opensearch.net.http.auth.pass", self.password)\
            .option("opensearch.net.ssl", "true")\
            .option("opensearch.net.ssl.cert.allow.self.signed", "true")\
            .option("opensearch.http.retries", "4")\
            .option("opensearch.http.timeout", "18000")\
            .option("opensearch.nodes.wan.only", "true")\
            .option("opensearch.batch.write.retry.policy", "simple")\
            .option("opensearch.batch.write.retry.count", "10")\
            .option('opensearch.batch.write.retry.wait', '30s') \
            .option('opensearch.update.retry.on.conflict', "10")\
            .mode("overwrite")\
            .save(index_nm)
```

This code works fine for non-error scenarios, but I need to test it to see how it would react in case of throttling or 429 errors. How can I write a unit test which returns errors during the "write"?

I've dealt with mocking python requests library, but this is just regular spark DF.write, converting to a opensearch format as it goes, sending batches of data at a time into the data sink. I don't know which object should be used as the Mock or how to simulate an error situation. Any code examples or pointers?

(Bonus points if you also know the answer to this question: How throttling would be handled from the Spark side in a multi-node situation (ie. if it throttles halfway, would half the data get written)?)